# How to stub an AJAX call using Sinon

Tags: jquery, ajax, sinon

I have a function that makes an AJAX request to an endpoint and gets back JSON. How can I fake that AJAX request using Sinon so that I can test that the function works properly?

Comment: Already tried the `Fake XMLHttpRequest` as it is mentioned on the [sinon.js](http://sinonjs.org/) page?

Answer (score 7):

If you are using `jQuery.ajax()`, you can stub it like this:

```
var returnData = {name: 'value'}
var stub = sinon.stub($, 'ajax');
stub.yieldsTo('success', returnData);
```

Then you write your test cases.

At the end, you should restore the original `jQuery.ajax()` function like this:

```
$.ajax.restore();
```