# How to test ajax calls in Jquery without sinon

Tags: jquery, ajax, testing

This might be a broad question but I am trying to test ajax calls in JQuery but somehow I cannot use sinon. Is there any way to test ajax calls?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to I stub an AJAX call using Sinon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41227513/how-to-i-stub-an-ajax-call-using-sinon)